# Grafana getting the metrics of current hour from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana

This is my query to get metrics from prometheus in Grafana:

`sum(increase(metricName{job="service"}[1h]))`

What I want, is that, for example if it is 14:23 now, the query to return only any metric with hour of 14 for today. I do not know how to achieve this. Because intervals and time-ranges are relative. For example, there is no option or variable or anything for CURRENT_HOUR or CURRENT_DAY in Grafana.

I would like to have a relatively absolute time such as CURRENT_HOUR or CURREN_DAY in grafana (something like a time macro). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana has time ranges that start from the beginning of a time period, such ranges are names `<Something> so far` (e.g. `Today so far`), see the [docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/time-range-controls/#time-units-and-relative-ranges). To make use of it in Prometheus query you need to replace `[1h]` with `[$__range]`. With `[$__range]` the effective time range for the panel will be converted to seconds before querying.

Putting these together, here's how you can create a panel with a query from the beginning of the hour:

[image: configure panel]

Unfortunately, `now` is not available for the `Relative time` field, so use `1s` instead. You'll get a panel like this:

[image: resulting panel]

This setup is not suitable for `graph` panels but on this one you can see that the left border begins at `13:00` and `[$__range]` was converted to seconds.

Comment: Grafan documentation says `now/d` and I expect `now/h` to work, but it doesn't. After all, `1s/h` seems to stretch the panel well, but why on top right corner of the panel it labels "last 1 second" ?

Comment: `now/d` works for dashboard-wide time range, `1s` is just a hack to replace `now` for the field. You can hide the `last 1 second` label with `Hide time info` switch.